# Unable to change environment is sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am using sequelize with NodeJs. I need to connect to the localhost database which is in the test env and not the development env.

`NODE_ENV= test` is defined in the `.env` file and I use the dotenv library.

In my model's `index.js`:

```
'use strict';

require('dotenv').config();
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

But when I try to connect to the DB, I get the following:

`Loaded configuration file "config\config.json"`

Using environment `development`:

```
ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Which means it is not reading the correct env.
Why is that?

Please note that I debugged the code and I made sure that config is reading the test JSON with the correct pass

Comment: Do you have `NODE_ENV= test` (with a space) ?  Try leaving out the space: `NODE_ENV=test`

Comment: same result, I made sure that process.env.NODE_ENV is reading test in the console, I really have no idea what is going on

Comment: What value does `use_env_variable` in your config.json have ?   Maybe you should add some debugging tot your code, and check the return values, until you find the cause.

Comment: use_env_variable does not exist in my config.json